# Receive input from microphone from 2 processes at once

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, javasound, sphinx4

I've been working on the java speech recognition using `sphynx4` and I currently have and issue.

I have an app that recognizes the microphone input using LiveSpeechRecognizer class of Sphynx4 which works fine. The issue is that after i added the class that also listens to microphone and transforms and visualizes the output.

Separately both classes works ok. But when combined in a single app i get the error:

> LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame,  not supported.

I have checked the issue and it seems to be caused by the simultaneous access to the microphone. I had an idea to use StreamSpeechRecognizer instead of a Live, but I failed to retrieve the stream from the microphone input. Tried AudioInputStream for that purpose.

Could you please suggest how can i adjust my code to get both: SpeechRecognition and Oscilloscope to use microphone simultaneously?

Thanks in advance.

UPD:

That's an my attempt to split the microphone input to use in both apps.

```
....
     byte[] data = new byte[dataCaptureSize];   
            line.read(data, 0, data.length);

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            out.write(data);
            byte audioData[] = out.toByteArray();
            InputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(byteArrayInputStream,
                    inputFormat,
                    audioData.length / inputFormat.getFrameSize());
....
```

That's how i convert it to the input stream which is than passed to the `StreamSpeechRecognizer` and the array of bytes is transformed with Fast Fourier Transform and passed to the graph. That doesn't work as it just freezes the graph all the time so the data displayed is not an actual one.

I tried to run recognition in separate thread but it didn't increase performance at all.

My code of splitting to threads is down below:

```
Thread recognitionThread = new Thread(new RecognitionThread(configuration,data));
    recognitionThread.join();
    recognitionThread.run();
```

UPD 2:
The input is from microphone.
The above AudioInputStream is passed to the StreamSpeechRecognizer:

`StreamSpeechRecognizer nRecognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
 nRecognizer.startRecognition(audioStream);`

And the byte array is passed transformed by FFT and passed to the graph:
`
    double[] arr = FastFourierTransform.TransformRealPart(data);

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(i*22050/(arr.length), arr[i]));
```

`

Comment: Is the first line.read statement coming from the microphone? If so, one assumes that there will be multiple reads while the mike line is open, yet you seem to be creating a new `ByteArrayOutputStream`, `InputStream` and `AudioInputStream` with each read. I can't tell how these Streams are being used from the code shown but logically the mike data should be progressively added to them if they are in turn being read elsewhere by the other sections of the program you are trying to implement. What is the point of the thread splitting? One can populate multiple streams in a single thread.

Comment: Just thought it would be faster. The stream is simply passed to the `StreamSpeechRecognizer recognize()` method

Comment: Yes. the line is from microphone. Added the code for how it is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plausible approach to consider.

First, write your own microphone reader. (There are tutorials on how to do this.) Then repackage that data as two parallel Lines that the other applications can read.

Another approach would be to check if either application has some sort of "pass through" capability enabled.

EDIT: added to clarify

This [Java sound record utility code example](https://www.codejava.net/coding/a-utility-for-recording-sound-in-java) opens a `TargetDataLine` to the microphone, and stores data from it into an array (lines 69, 70). Instead of storing the data in an array, I'm suggesting that you create two `SourceDataLine` objects and write the data out to each.

```
recordBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
secondStreamBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

isRunning = true;

while (isRunning) {
    bytesRead = audioLine.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    recordBytes.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    secondStreamBytes.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Hopefully it won't be too difficult to figure out how to configure your two programs to read from the created lines rather than from the microphone's line. I'm unable to provide guidance on how to do that.

EDIT 2:
I wish some other people would join in. I'm a little over my head with doing anything fancy with streams. And the code you are giving is so minimal I still don't understand what is happening or how things are connecting.

FWTW: (1) Is the data you are adding into "series1" is the streaming data? If so, can you add a line in that `for` loop, and  write the same data to a stream consumed by the other class? (This would be a way of using the microphone data "in series" as opposed to "in parallel.")

(2) Data streams often involves code that blocks or that runs at varying paces due to the unpredictable way in which the cpu switches between tasks. So if you do write a "splitter" (as I tried to illustrate by modifying the microphone reading code I linked earlier) there could arise a situation where the code will only run as fast as the slower of the two "splits" at the given moment. You may need to incorporate some sort of buffering and use separate threads for the two recipients of the mike data.

I wrote my first buffering code recently, for a situation where a microphone-reading line is sending a stream to an audio-mixing funtion on another thread. I only wrote this a few weeks ago and it's the first time I dealt with trying to run a stream across a thread barrier threads, so I don't know if the idea I came up with is the best way to do this sort of thing. But it does manage to keep the feed from the mike to the mixer steady with no drop outs and no losses.

The mike reader reads a buffer of data, then adds this `byte[]` buffer into a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Byte[]>`.

From the other thread, the audio-mixing code polls the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for data.

I experimented a bit and currently have the size of the byte[] buffer at 512 bytes and the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is set to hold up to 12 "buffers" before it starts throwing away the oldest buffers (the structure is FIFO). This seems to be enough of these small buffers to accommodate when the microphone processing code temporarily gets ahead of the mixer.

The `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` has built in provisions to allow adding and polling to occur from two threads at the same time without throwing an exception. Whether this is something you have to write to help with a hand off, and what the best buffer size might be, I can't say. Maybe a much larger buffer with fewer buffers held in the Queue would be better.

Maybe someone else will weigh in, or maybe the suggestion will be worth experimenting with and trying out.

Anyway, that's about the best I can do, given my limited experience with this. I hope you are able to work something out.

Comment: Not quite sure that i understand you. The problem is that i have a microphone reader and it's working just fine. But for another process - speech to text the microphone reader is packed inside the jar and is triggered when the recognize method is called. I cannot affect it or pass the bytes to it.

Comment: I will add to the answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. The problem is that it is almost the same code as is used to pass data to the waveform graph in my second app. If i would get `SourceDataLine` it is still not clear how i can pass it to the `LiveSpeechRecognizer` class instance from recognition app.

Comment: Yes, you will need, from BOTH apps, either a way to configure which line is used for input or be able to do a little recoding that allows you to specify the input line. Sounds like you can do this with the waveform graph program but not the `LiveSpeechRecognizer`.

Comment: Just did a quick flyover of Sphynx. I don't see where the input is occurring in the code. But they have a forum on sourceforge. Someone there should be able to let you know where the rewrite would have to occur. They may even have already provisioned for this.

Comment: Thats right. I cannot rewrite the `LiveSpeechRecognizer`. At least i failed to find a way to. I tried to use the 'StreamSpeechRecognizer' but it reqires an input stream. Any way i can get it from the microphone input and not the file?

Comment: I got confused. Are both functions from the same program? If you can identify the point in each where the input stream is referenced, I might be able to help, further. But I encourage you again to also check with the makers of the program.

Comment: Basically i have currently the program that builds a graph using dataline from the microphone input. And i also have the speech recognition app which is basically a demo app from the website. It calls the method recognize from the classs `LiveSpeechRecognizer` and that's basically it. I also found another class which is StreamSpeechRecognizer. I have found the usage example when the input stream was created from a file and passed  as a parameter. So the main idea that i tried to achieve was to get input stream not from the file but from the 1st app that i have and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Did you write the code for the graphical display? If so, that is where you use the splitter concept I described. Communicating between two apps probably means creating a network socket output as part of the first app (the graphics display app) and copying the data read from the microphone into a second stream that outputs through the network socket. From the tutorial on `StreamSpeechRecognizer` they say that getting the InputStream from a NetworkSocket is possible.

Comment: The idea is to get a single app at the end. So i guess the communication part can be skipped. I already tried to pass AudioInputStream to the  `StreamSpeechRecognizer` from the part with a graph but it didn't work. It might be that i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Done. Hope you will understand my explanation.

Comment: Added to my answer.

Comment: Well you for sure have more experience that me. And i would say your comments are very informative. I experimented a lot already with this classes but the solution you propose is not among those i tried. I cannot say that i understood everything but i will try it. As for the source code, i can mail it to you if you want.

Comment: I'm a bit swamped with other obligations at the moment (e.g., have to take a final in the next few days). I could maybe take a look next week, give the problem a half-hour or so. I would want you to clearly identify the input points, I don't want to spend time searching for them. Meanwhile, do keep experimenting. I know that many times in coding I've had to step back & take some time to study a topic in more depth before jumping back in. That may be the case for you here. If you can, perhaps just try writing a simple program that only does a simple pass-through or split, as a stepping stone.